# A column can change it's content in every two years starting from an another (type datetime) column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Let's begin with the purpose of the project :

-> I have a table with a column `Date_Election_President` the type is `Datetime`...

Begin with the day of his election, the President cannot reach more than two years

And in the same table I have an another column `President_Eligible` of type `varchar(3)` which takes only 'Yes' or 'No'

- Yes - if the President did not complete the two years yet
- No - if the President did complete the two years

I'm asking you if there is any way in SQL Server to automatically change the `President_Eligible` column from 'Yes' to 'No' if the President did complete the two years?

This is the table

```
create table GIAC
(
    Id_GIAC smallint primary key identity(1,1),
    Nom varchar(50) not null,
    Adress varchar(50) not null,

    President varchar(50) not null,
    President_Eligible varchar(20),
    Date_Election_President datetime,
)
```

Comment: Instead of storing it, why don't you compute it in your query?

Comment: sorry .. i dont understand ??

Comment: Instead of storing this data in the database, when you go to retrieve whether or not a President is eligible, you do the calculations based off of the Date in the database.  That way you don't have to update anything, you just determine eligibility whenever the data is queried.

Comment: thnks Stefan ...nice idea .. tnks a loooooooot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, if you *do* want it "in" your table, you can use a computed column:

```
create table GIAC
(
    Id_GIAC smallint primary key identity(1,1),
    Nom varchar(50) not null,
    Adress varchar(50) not null,

    President varchar(50) not null,
    Date_Election_President datetime,
    President_Eligible as CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day,Date_Election_President,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) >= 730 THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END
)
```

And then you don't have to remember to include this logic in every query - putting it in every query is a risk if the rule will ever change.

I've also changed to counting the number of days since election, rather than doing `DATEDIFF(year,...`, since `DATEDIFF` counts the number of *transitions* of the identified date portion between the two dates. For instance, the `DATEDIFF(year,...` between 31st December 2011 and 1st January 2012 is 1.

Comment: i have to modify the column in my database i write this : 

ALTER TABLE GIAC
alter column President_Eligible varchar(3) as CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day,Date_Election_President,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) >= 730 THEN 'NON' ELSE 'OUI' END

i face this problem :
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.

Comment: @Yassineedouiri - you can't specify the type of a computed column - it's inferred from the resulting type of the expression that defines it. If you want it to be `varchar(3)`, wrap the whole `CASE` expression with a `CONVERT` - `President_Eligible as CONVERT(varchar(3),CASE ... END)`

Answer (score 2):

Adding my Comment in answer form, with a little more info:

Instead of storing eligibility data in the database, when you go to retrieve whether or not a President is eligible, you do the calculations based off of the Date in the database. That way you don't have to update anything, you just determine eligibility whenever the data is queried.

An example query:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(year, Date_Election_President , GetDate() ) >= 2 
        THEN 'Yes' 
        ELSE 'No' 
    END
```

And info for using DATEDIFF: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx